# MongoDB PECL extension for CodeIgniter throw an error

Tags: mongodb, codeigniter, nginx, php-7

I'm a very beginner with MongoDB.
I wanted to use it with my CodeIgniter 3.x framework, so I followed this tutorial :

https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/wiki/Using-MongoDB-in-Codeigniter

I mention that I'm using PHP7 with NGINX.
I have also installed some "php extensions" required (like: "php-pear", "php7.0-xml", so on)

Unfortunately, after having installed all that stuff, my webpage throw this error :

> An Error Was Encountered
>
> The MongoDB PECL extension has not been installed or enabled

I already gave a look to similiars questions which were posted several weeks or months ago, but I didn't manage to find a solution to my problem....

If you think that more informations are needed in purpose to help me, tell me :)

Comment: Does the MongoDB extension show up within `phpinfo()`'s output?

Comment: Yes : MongoDB extension version  1.2.4
MongoDB extension stability  stable 
so on....